# How to expect an test fail if I have a test case not implemented in Postman?

Tags: postman, postman-testcase

I'm writing API testing using Postman. I plan to write a failed test when I'm not implement the API yet.

I'm writing this at this moment.

```
pm.test("Not implement yet", function () {
    pm.expect(true).to.eql(false);
});
```

Is there something like this in Postman? I just want a test to be fail.

```
pm.test("Not implement yet", function () {
    pm.expect().fail();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pm.expect.fail('This failed because ...');`

Comment: I was not able to find documentation about this API before. Now I realized that it is from **ChaiJS expect BDD syntax** https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/